# Laravel - Data is not being displayed using a all

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Using the code below resulting in an empty array

```
$data = M_Obat::all();
```

While using the code below resulting in an array containing 2 data

```
$data = DB::table('master.ruangan')->get();
```

Attached images:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSc9Z.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBylo.png

Comment: Yeah Gicu's answer is probably correct, however you give us no information regarding what your model looks like or anything. [How do I ask a good question? | Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would probably be usefull to read

Answer (score 2):

probably your model (M_Obat) is not correctly related to the right table:

try to specify it in your model class:

```
protected $table = 'master.ruangan';
```

Answer (score 0):

check your model for 'hidden'

if a variable called $hidden is declared in model, fields added in it will not be shown.

```
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];
```

Comment: that's for hiding proprieties (columns) but he doesn't get results (rows).

Answer (score 0):

`$data = M_Obat::all()`

Data that you want it exists in `#attributes`